# #1064 ERROR when trying to make an trigger sql

Tags: triggers, mariadb

When I am trying to run my sql code that should create an trigger

```
create trigger userid_to_tokens
after insert on users
as
begin
    insert into tokens
        (token_id)
        select i.user_id
        from users t
        inner join inserted i on t.user_id=i.user_id
end
```

> ERROR:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as begin insert into tokens (token_id) select i.user_id ' at line 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `as` with `for each row`, change the delimiter and in MySQL it is `NEW` instead of `inserted`

```
delimiter //
create trigger userid_to_tokens
after insert on users
for each row
begin
    insert into tokens (token_id) VALUES (NEW.user_id);
end
//
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

As mariadb documentation on [create trigger](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-trigger/) shows, there is no `as` keyword before the `begin` keyword. The quoted code in the syntax error message indicates this by starting the code excerpt with the `as ...`.